# AWS | Syntax error in module': invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-2.7, stomp, amazon-mq

I have created python script which is uploaded as a zip file in AWS Lambda function with stompy libraries bundled in them.

Logs for python 2.7:-

```
Response:
null

Request ID:
"c334839f-ee46-11e8-8970-612f1dc92e41"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: c334839f-ee46-11e8-8970-612f1dc92e41 Version: $LATEST
CONNECTION Started
CONNECTION established
CONNECTION Subscribed
[WARNING]   2018-11-22T11:07:12.798Z    c334839f-ee46-11e8-8970-612f1dc92e41    Unknown response frame type: '' (frame length was 3)
END RequestId: c334839f-ee46-11e8-8970-612f1dc92e41
REPORT RequestId: c334839f-ee46-11e8-8970-612f1dc92e41  Duration: 10027.75 ms   Billed Duration: 10100 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 30 MB
```

My Code:-

```
import time
import boto3
import stomp

kinesis_client = boto3.client('kinesis')


class Listener(stomp.ConnectionListener):
    msg_list = []
    def on_error(self, headers, message):
        print('received an error "%s"' % message)

    def on_message(self, headers, message):
        print('received a message "%s"' % message)
        kinesis_client.put_record(
            StreamName='Purchasing',
            Data=u'{}\r\n'.format(message).encode('utf-8'),
            PartitionKey='0'
        )


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    conn = stomp.Connection(host_and_ports=[('b-4714-4441-8166-47aae158281a-1.mq.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com', 8162)])
    lst = Listener()
    conn.set_listener('Listener', Listener())
    conn.start()
    conn.connect(login='test_mq', passcode='test_mq')
    conn.subscribe(destination='/queue/Purchasing', id='b-4714-4441-8166-47aae158281a', ack='auto')
    message = lst.msg_list
    print('Waiting for messages "%s"' % message)
    time.sleep(10)
    conn.disconnect()
    return ''
```

I am not sure why my message is not showing up in my output,instead it always shows up "Response: null".

Comment: Please post your code as text, not a screenshot.  We might need to copy and paste your code to our own text editors to reproduce your problem, and we can't do that from a graphic.

Comment: @cdarke I have attached the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: As pointed by @Petesh, the issue comes from `stompy`(external library), which hasn't been ported to Python3.

If you check the source code, you can find this:

```
except socket.timeout, exc:
```

which is invalid syntax for python3+

If you run your Lambdas in python3.6/3.7 environment, the syntax is invalid.

The issue might go away if you choose python 2.7, but you will also have to adjust your code, libraries, etc.

Comment: Can you clarify that the issue is with the `stompy` module, which has not been ported to python3 - it's not clear from your answer that this is what's the trigger of the issue.

Comment: @AlexK.. Thank you.. What adjustments I need to do to my code if I choose python 2.7. Moreover, How or where can I get python3+ stompy libraries

Comment: @AlexK.. Also I have updated the error logs for python 2.7

Comment: This https://pypi.org/project/stomp.py/#description looks like a  alternative for python 3

Comment: @AlexK I have used your link https://pypi.org/project/stomp.py/#files and downloaded tar.gz file. But it doesn't have stomp.py files in it

Comment: Please just execute this `pip install stomp.py`. Also I can confirm there are files when you extract the .tar

Comment: Thank you @AlexK.. I got ew error now. I am really sorry to trouble you along. As a new bee, I need some guidance from you.

Comment: Well, you have to actually mention what error you got

Comment: I have attached them in the question:-
File "/var/task/one_purchasing.py", line 23, in lambda_handler
    conn.set_listener('', Listener(conn))
TypeError: object() takes no parameters

Comment: Well, unfortunately, my work hours are over, so I will have to go, but here you are trying to inherit a class `ConnectionListener` which takes no arguments and you are passing some to it. You can just read the docs in the link I  have posted above and follow them and you should be fine.

Comment: @AlexK I have updated the question with latest error message. Please suggest. Is there any possible way that we can connect. Its been week I am trying to understand and close this:(

Comment: Increase the lambda execution time, it is set to 3 seconds by default and you make the handler sleep for 10 seconds.

Comment: @AlexK I have changed the timeout value to 30sec and observed errors. 
Errors:-
START RequestId: eedddb94-ed7a-11e8-9e5a-ab744fd1f9da Version: $LATEST
Waiting for messages...
'StompConnection11' object has no attribute 'close': AttributeError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/one_purchasing.py", line 29, in lambda_handler
    conn.close()
AttributeError: 'StompConnection11' object has no attribute 'close'

END RequestId: eedddb94-ed7a-11e8
REPORT RequestId: eedddb94-ed7a-11e8 Duration: 10021.06 ms Billed Duration: 10100 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 31

Comment: @AlexK . Please suggest

Comment: Use `.disconnect` rather than `.close`

Comment: Thanka a lot @AlexK That worked..:) Another quick question-- How will my cloudwatch events capture my messages and send it to my Lambda function

Comment: Cloudwatch isn't the tool for that task. Check SQS and SNS. But this is a different question already

Comment: I am using AWS MQ , so I have no option other than Cloudwatch to capture messages and send it across to Lambda then to Kinesis.
https://github.com/aws-samples/amazonmq-invoke-aws-lambda
My architecture

Comment: As I said this is no longer in the scope of the question. I cannot help you much with that.

Comment: @AlexK-- I feel my code is having issues. Its not able to pick messages sent from MQ

Comment: @AlexK I am receiving "Response: null". I am not sure where exactly is the error. Please suggest

Comment: Post another question with different tags and different topic/description. I cannot help you out with STOMP protocol. I answered to the question you have posted here.

Comment: @AlexK-- I posted a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53430332/result-returned-by-aws-lambda-python-function-execution-in-null please suggest

Comment: @AlexK- Could you please suggest anything here plz--https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53445120/aws-kinesis-put-record-from-one-aws-account-to-different-account