# Result returned by AWS Lambda python function execution in ""Null""

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-mq

I have a python script which connects to AWS MQ and collect message. All my connections are perfectly aligned and Execution result is success. But result returned by my function execution is "null".
 Updated error logs:-

```
    {
  "errorType": "ConnectFailedException",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/one_purchasing.py\", line 21, in lambda_handler\n    conn.connect(login='test_mq', passcode='test_secure_mq',wait=True)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/stomp/connect.py\", line 164, in connect\n    Protocol11.connect(self, *args, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/stomp/protocol.py\", line 340, in connect\n    self.transport.wait_for_connection()\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/stomp/transport.py\", line 327, in wait_for_connection\n    raise exception.ConnectFailedException()\n"
  ]
}
```

Updated Python Lambda function:-

```
import time
import boto3
import stomp
import json

kinesis_client = boto3.client('kinesis')


class Listener(stomp.ConnectionListener):
    def on_error(self, headers, message):
        print('received an error "%s"' % message)
        kinesis_client.put_record(
            StreamName='OnePurchasing',
            Data=u'{}\r\n'.format(message).encode('utf-8'),
            PartitionKey='0'
        )

    def on_message(self, headers, message):
        print('received a message "%s"' % message)
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    conn = stomp.Connection(host_and_ports=[('b-fa99d7c5-4714-4441-8166-47aae158281a-1.mq.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com', 61614)])
    lst = Listener()
    conn.set_listener('Listener', lst)
    conn.set_ssl(for_hosts=[('b-fa99d7c5-4714-4441-8166-47aae158281a-1.mq.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com', 61614)])
    conn.start()
    print('CONNECTION Started')
    conn.connect(login='test_mq', passcode='test_secure_mq',wait=True)
    print('CONNECTION established')
    conn.subscribe(destination='/queue/OnePurchasing', id=1, ack='auto')
    print('CONNECTION Subscribed')
    time.sleep(10)
    conn.disconnect()
    return
```

Could anyone tell me how can I debug more to get the message from MQ

MQ URL message screen shot

[MQ home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1ZrI.png)

[Messages under queue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVzW6.png)

Comment: Not sure it's the cause of your problem but according to https://github.com/jasonrbriggs/stomp.py/issues/33 you should make your port a string rather than int `, '61614')])` to make the strange warning disappear. Curious to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @EricDarchis I tested, it does not make a difference, the strange warning remains.

Comment: @EricDarchis .. Yes.. it did not make any difference..

Comment: @Tinku regarding your edit to my answer, you probably want to change that in your question too :-)

Comment: @RobBricheno-- I have posted different question- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53445120/python-aws-kinesis-put-record-from-one-user-to-different-user

Comment: @RobBricheno-- I have updated my questions with my findings. Is there any URL where I can get this info. Please suggest.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53445120/aws-kinesis-put-record-from-one-user-to-different-user

Comment: @RobBricheno- I have sent JSON format message in my MQ, its not considering complete JSON message as a single message instead each value inside JSON as a message. Moreover- in my Kinesis stream, I am unable to see the JSON format message:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that `response` is `null` is because you don't ever return a value, you just `return`. It's the same response as if you run this:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return
```

You probably want to return something, like the example built in to lambda:

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

Regarding the rest of your problem, it looks like you are never receivng a message at all. You see from [the web console of your MQ instance](http://b-4714-4441-8166-47aae158281a-1.mq.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:8162) if there are messages on the queue, if a message has been consumed, and so on.

All the examples I have seen involve using the `wait=True` option e.g. `conn.connect(wait=True)` so you should try adding that to your `conn.connect` unless there's a good reason you aren't using it.

**Edit:** I tested this, I don't think you are ever establishing a connection. If you add `wait=True` then you will probably see that the connection fails with a `ConnectFailedException` as mine did. This is probably the first thing to debug.

**Edit 2:** I solved it, you need to use SSL for your connection to the AWS MQ instance as follows:

```
conn = stomp.Connection(host_and_ports=[('b-4714-4441-8166-47aae158281a-1.mq.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com', 61614)])
lst = Listener()
conn.set_listener('Listener', lst)
conn.set_ssl(for_hosts=[('b-4714-4441-8166-47aae158281a-1.mq.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com', 61614)])
conn.start()
```

Comment: I have updated response and code as well. MQ does has messages in it. Updated with proper URL of MQ with credentials. Please suggest

Comment: @Tinku did you try `wait=True`?

Comment: Yeah.. Even I received   "errorType": "ConnectFailedException",
 error

Comment: How can I proceed from here. As I have given all the right values which I have

Comment: @Tinku check latest edit, I solved it, you need to use SSL :-)

Comment: I have updated the code now, How can I put these messages into Kinesis..? Final suggestion.

Comment: @Tinku You'd probably add some code to the `on_message` function of your listener. But really that's quite a different, new question. Why don't you try a few things, and if you hit a problem post a new question about it?

Comment: Could you suggest me anything here--https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53445120/aws-kinesis-put-record-from-one-aws-account-to-different-account